# How to insert implementation of abstract type as generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types, dependency-injection, abstract

**EDIT 1 : Changing overloaded MemoryPersistency constructor to explicitly expect an XmlParser solves the issue :**

```
public MemoryPersistency(IDictionary<ID, T> objectsMap, IDiskPersistency<XmlParser<IDictionary<ID,T>>, IDictionary<ID, T>, string> diskPersistency)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
        this.diskPersistency = diskPersistency;
        this.objectsMap = objectsMap;

    }
```

**But, my goal is to make MemoryPersistency work with any kind of parser, as long as it inherits Parser abstract class.**

I'm working on an application, in which I have to develop a generic `diskPersistency` module which works fine by it's own. The problem is when i try to inject this `diskPersistency` type in `MemoryPersistency` class.

Let me explain: this class's constructor has an overload where I can pass in a `diskPersistency` so it can be used.

```
public class MemoryPersistency<T, ID> : IPersistency<T, IDictionary<ID, T>, ID> 
{
    public event EventHandler? ObjectAdded;
    private IDictionary<ID, T> objectsMap { get; set; }
    private IDiskPersistency<Parser<IDictionary<ID,T>,string>, IDictionary<ID,T>, string>? diskPersistency;

    public MemoryPersistency(IDictionary<ID, T> objectsMap)
    {
        this.objectsMap = objectsMap;
    }

    public MemoryPersistency(IDictionary<ID, T> objectsMap, IDiskPersistency<Parser<IDictionary<ID, T>, string>, IDictionary<ID, T>, string> diskPersistency)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
        this.diskPersistency = diskPersistency;
        this.objectsMap = objectsMap;
    }
}
```

`Parser` is an abstract type that defines the basic needs of a parser that can be used by `DiskPersistency`:

```
public abstract class Parser<TSource,TTarget> : ISerializer<TSource,TTarget> 
{
    public abstract Type AcceptsType { get; }
    public abstract Type ReturnsType { get; }
    public abstract TSource deserialize(TTarget target);
    public abstract TTarget serialize(TSource source);
}
```

Then this `XmlParser` inherits from `Parser` like this :

```
public class XmlParser<TSource> : Parser<TSource, string>
{
    public XmlParser(string pathToDisk)
    {
        this.pathToDisk = pathToDisk;
    }

    public string pathToDisk { get; set; }

    public override Type AcceptsType => typeof(TSource);
    public override Type ReturnsType => typeof(string);

    public override TSource deserialize(String target)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TSource));

        using (var _reader = new FileStream(target, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            TSource result = (TSource)s.Deserialize(_reader);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public override string serialize(TSource source)
    {
        XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TSource));
        var target = pathToDisk + "/" + typeof(TSource) + ".xml";

        using (var _writer = new StreamWriter(target))
        {
            _serializer.Serialize(_writer, source);
            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

At last, here's how my `DiskPersistency` class is defined :

```
public class DiskPersistency<TParser,TSource,TTarget> : IDiskPersistency<TParser,TSource,TTarget> where TParser : ISerializer<TSource,TTarget>
{
    public TParser parser { get; set; }

    public DiskPersistency(TParser parser)
    {
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public TTarget persistToDisk(TSource source)
    {
        return parser.serialize(source);
    }

    public TSource getFromDisk(TTarget path)
    {
        return parser.deserialize(path);
    }
}
```

All tests concerning `diskPersistency` work on their own. The problem happens when I try to inject a `DiskPersistency` object into `MemoryPersistency`:

```
 var diskPersistency = new DiskPersistency<XmlParser<ObjectAdapter>, ObjectAdapter, string>(new XmlParser<ObjectAdapter>(Environment.CurrentDirectory));

 this.memory = new MemoryPersistency<ObjectAdapter, int>(new Dictionary<int,ObjectAdapter>(), diskPersistency);
```

The error is that `XmlParser<TSource>` cannot be converted to `Parser<TSource, TTarget>` even though I inherited from `Parser` (using `XmlParser<TSource> : Parser<TSource,string>` and overriding `Parser` method).

Am I doing something wrong in my class definitions?

Hope someone can help, I'm running out of hair. Thanks!

Comment: The way the C# type system works, `Parser<object, string>` is considered a different type altogether than `Parser<string, string>`. So you cannot simply swap one for the other. It also seems like you are mixing several fundamentally different concepts (parsing, serialization, disk IO) and trying to put them into a common set of interfaces, which is likely violating the [Liskov Substitution Principal](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/liskov-substitution-principle/).

Comment: I recommend reading [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) by Mark Seemann to get a handle on these concepts, which can save you a lot of hair!

Comment: It's not a direct solution., but thanks for these links. I know that the problem come from the way i'm structuring elements. But i'd really like suggestion on how i can make my code better.

Comment: Persisting to disk is already distilled down to converting between `Stream` (of which there are many different types) and other types. That will get you a way to save a *binary* file (which is the most performant option). Add a `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` and you can save a *text* file. `Stream`, `TextReader` and `TextWriter` are all abstract so you can provide your own implementations if none of the existing ones are adequate. `XmlSerializer` is a decorator for Stream. It isn't clear what you hope to gain with your persistency objects because these can already be swapped.

Comment: I'll try then binary option ! This isn't a real case scenario, it is a test. So I'm trying to implement various possible ways of serializing what was persistent in memory. Thanks for the binary idea !

Comment: Well, do note that the [`BinarySerializer` is now obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization) and Microsoft recommends to limit the amount of types that are serializable to DTOs and collections to prevent security breaches. To move data between object graph and stream, add `Serialize`/`Deserialize` methods to your objects and call `BinaryWriter`/`BinaryReader` calls in a specific order. For collections, you will need to store the `Count` property first so you know how many times to loop to round trip the values.

Comment: Binary serialization also can be fragile if you want to change the format - you may need to design the app to be able to read legacy binary formats as it evolves, which requires some planning. If that is too much maintenance and performance isn't the primary concern, JSON or XML serialization might be simpler to manage.

Comment: Interesting ! Now that it is working, i have to find a way to make MemoryPersistency work with any class that inherits Parser

Comment: If you base your methods on `Stream`, then all you need to do is provide a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream`. Done.